# Disable click event outside of bootstrap modal area to close modal in angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-modal

I am new in anguar4. I am using bootstrap modal in my project. Modal is going to hide when click on outside of modal. 
here is my code

//in html

```
<div bsModal #noticeModal="bs-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
    aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel"
    aria-hidden="true">

    <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
        <div class="modal-content">
              Hello World
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

// in ts code

```
@ViewChild('noticeModal') public noticeModal: ModalDirective;

ngAfterViewInit() {
   this.noticeModal.show();
};
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

please add this config's in html. Hope it will help your problem.

```
<div bsModal #noticeModal="bs-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
    [config]="{backdrop: 'static',  keyboard: false}" 
    aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel"
    aria-hidden="true">

    <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
        <div class="modal-content">
              Hello World
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, It is not working for me. It is giving error: Can't bind to 'config' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.

Comment: This usually happens when one doesn't properly configure the bsModal directive in their module.

Comment: possibly this solution is for development made in JQuery. not compatible with Angular html development.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using button to open popup, then use below config on button,

```
<button data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" 
data-backdrop="static" 
data-keyboard="false">
```

Comment: **data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false"**  These are the key attributes. But they need to be added where the modal is declared not on the <button> tag.

Answer (score 1):

Below solution work for me by adding `{backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false}；` when call the modal --> `$('#myModal').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false})；`

It work for me without adding `bsModal` into `<div>` or any directive modules.

A clearer solution as shown below:
HTML:

```
 <div #crudModal class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal Title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">        
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">       
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In .ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@ViewChild('crudModal') crudModal: ElementRef;

openModal() {
    $(this.crudModal.nativeElement).modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false});
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

**btw**, if you'll use the component approach for bsModal via **BsModalService**, *you can simply set*: `ignoreBackdropClick = false`(Ignore the backdrop click)
as it described in the Angular Bootstrap API reference

**your.component.ts**

```
constructor(private bsModalService: BsModalService) {}

const bsModal = this.bsModalService.show(YourModalComponent, {
    class: 'modal-dialog-centered modal-md',
    ignoreBackdropClick: true
});
```

P.S. It is better to use this approach than inside of your HTML template. Think about reusability ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use `backdrop: 'static'` option, as listed in the documentation in [here](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#%2Fmodal)